# Coldfusion unnecessary http calls

Tags: coldfusion

I am using coldfusion 9 as application server, with JQuery as front end or UI.
when I call any cfm page, there are many http calls shown in the console or in firebug, I dont under stand why and how to stop these calls because I can see it slowing down my page
here is the console log when I load a cfm page

```
GET http://localhost/iraqtcs/entities/manifest/cfc/ma...ientid=D33EEE9C786C65DD63267E40E30218A2&_cf_rc=2
cfajax.js (line 147)

GET http://localhost/iraqtcs/entities/manifest/cfc/ma...ientid=D33EEE9C786C65DD63267E40E30218A2&_cf_rc=3
cfajax.js (line 147)

GET http://localhost/iraqTCS/entities/manifest/create....cfm?manifestID=AA03A9C98108819D&nls=203&index=1
jquery-....min.js (line 4)

GET http://localhost/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/messages/cfmessage.js?_=1439798341134
jquery-....min.js (line 4)

GET http://localhost/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/package/cfajax.js?_=1439798341267
jquery-....min.js (line 4)

GET http://localhost/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/yui/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js?_=1439798341328
jquery-....min.js (line 4)

GET http://localhost/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/yui/animation/animation-min.js?_=1439798341368 jquery-....min.js (line 4)

GET http://localhost/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/yui/autocomplete/autocomplete-min.js?_=1439798341429query-....min.js (line 4)

GET http://localhost/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/package/cfautosuggest.js?_=1439798341475 jquery-....min.js (line 4)

GET http://localhost/CFIDE/scripts/cfform.js?_=1439798341527 jquery-....min.js (line 4)

GET http://localhost/CFIDE/scripts/masks.js?_=1439798341560
```

as you can see there is 3 hits from my code (valid http calls)
and there is 8 unnecessary http calls, can anyone help me here??

Comment: `<cfajaximport>` do you have this tag in your page?

Comment: Are you using any JS libraries included in ColdFusion? If you are using the features like `cfwindow`, `cfform` then these JS files get included in your html page and hence the HTTP requests.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are using some of the ColdFusion UI components (`cfform`, `cfdiv`, etc). I would suggest you stop using them. They are woefully out of date, limited in functionality and poorly implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following are the JS, CSS files added by coldfusion in order to support `cfajaximport, cfdiv, cflayout, cfpod, cfwindow, cfform` etc in your pages. While using these tags in your page, these files are necessary.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/messages/cfmessage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/package/cfajax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/yui/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/yui/animation/animation-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/ext/adapter/yui/ext-yui-adapter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/ext/ext-all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/package/cfwindow.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/resources/ext/css/ext-all.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/resources/cf/cf.css" />
```

`<cfajaximport>` Do you have this tag in your page?

Are you using any JS libraries included in ColdFusion? If you are using the features like `cfwindow`, `cfform` then these JS files get included in your html page and hence the HTTP requests.

In case you are not using any of the features, then you can remove the `<cfajaximport>` tag and see if this problem still exists.

Its better to use external libraries for modal windows and other features because of such issue.

Comment: I dont use <cfajaximport> in any page of my code. and I use cfform  and cfwindow

Comment: @HamzehHirzallah the extra files being loaded are the libraries for the `cfwindow`s and `cfform`s. Unless you get rid of them all you need these files to be loaded and I am not aware of any ways to avoid these files with these special tags in use.